# Wrap IMG element inside an Elementor Lightbox gallery(on Wordpress) with A tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Here is my code to target a specific image:

```
jQuery('img[src="https://hello.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/Email-Newsletter-scaled.jpg"]').wrap('<a href="https://hello.com"></a>');
```

My code works on images outside of the light-box gallery. Not sure why its not working on images inside. Thank you.

Comment: Could you pls share site url where we can check this issue

Comment: Could be that your code is executed before the lightbox images are added to the page. Try wrapping it in a setTimeout of a couple of seconds to verify.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, setTimeout did the trick !